# Using the :only-child selector with $(this)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to invoke slideToggle on a div in the page based on the href of an anchor inside a list item. I've never used the :only-child selector before, is there a reason I can't use it with (this)?

```
$('li').click(function(){
    var requiredID = $(this:only-child).attr('href');
    $('#requiredID').slideToggle();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QW32X/2/

To clarify, the particular interface I'm working on is going to require that the li itself be clicked on, which is why I can't just get the id directly from the anchor itself.

Comment: Why exactly do you need `:only-child`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there is no need to use it but if you want to seek for the `a` element that is the only child this will work

```
$('li').click(function(){
    var requiredID = $(this).children("a:only-child").attr("href")
    $(requiredID).slideToggle();
});
```

Working [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QW32X/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can, but you can't append it to a variable. Try this:

```
var requiredID = $(this).filter(':only-child').attr('href');
```

Better:

```
$('li:only-child').click(function(){
    var requiredID = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#requiredID').slideToggle();
});
```

All that said, this won't work because you have no only-child list items in your fiddle. Furthermore, no list should be created with the intention of it only having one item. That's not much of a list.